# How can I lower wall cabinets after fitting drywall?

Tags: drywall, kitchens, installation, cabinets

Before fitting a drywall, I measured 12cm from the ceiling and fitted battens (wall studs) across the length of the room to support wall cabinets.

I didn't leave enough room - the wall cabinets are now too high.

Does anything exist such as a metal piece that will act as a lowering mechanism to keep the existing support at the 12cm but allow the cupboard to hang lower e.g. at 24cm from the ceiling. I'm imagining a piece of metal that hooks to both the wall fixture and the cupboard but I'm not sure if it exists.

The battens are 1.5 inches because I needed to bring it in front of some pipes.

Also open to other suggestions.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't attach to studs like everyone else?

Comment: The studs (wooden battens) have already gone in and are incorrectly placed behind the wall

Comment: can you post a picture or a diagram?

Comment: Hey bib, no need - already have my answer below. Just sharing incase anybody else needs the same answer. Lesson learnt, measure your studs (battens) properly before putting on your plasterboard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work out the correct height the battens (studs) should be, cut the plasterboard using a sharp knife or angle grinder and neat as possible and place in the battens where you want them to be. Screw your plasterboard back onto your newly placed batten and polyfill the gaps if you care about tidyness. You can then safely attach your cupboard to the newly placed batten and the cut out will not be seen because it will be behind the cupboard. Hey Presto!

Credit: Father.